# How to select json items base on their parent in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'd like to have two select boxes for users to mention their location data. 
When user chooses the province `Bar` from the first select box, the second selct box should be populated with the cities of the province:

Here is the json data:

```
  Provinces: [
  {
    "Province": "Foo",
    "Cities": [
      {
        "name": "Fooland"
      },
      {
        "name": "Fooville"
      }

  } ,

  {"Province": "Bar",
    "Cities": [
      {
        "name": "Barland"
      },
      {
        "name": "Barville"
      },
      {
        "name": "Barak"
      }

  } 
 ]
```

The province select box works fine:

```
<select v-model="province">                   
 <option v-for="(p, index) in provinces" :key="index" >{{ p.Province }}</option>
 selected: {{province}},
</select>
```

But I can not get the cities of `Bar` in the second select box:

```
<select v-model="city">                   
     <option v-for="(c, index) in provinces.province.Cities" :key="index">{{ c.name }}</option>      
</select>
```

Appreciate your hints on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR:** Change the first `<select>`'s value to be the selected province *object* (which contains `Cities`), and use that value to populate the second `<select>`'s options.

---

The value of `<select>` is the value of the selected `<option>`. if you don't explicitly specify a value for an `<option>`, the [default value is the `<option>`s inner text](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#attr-value) (standard behavior). So, you can assign a value that is different from the `<option>` label, and the value can be an object:

```
<option :value="myOptionValue">My Option Label</option>
```

Thus, you can assign the underlying province object model (i.e., `p` in this case) to the `<option>`s in the provinces `<select>`:

```
<option :value="p" v-for="(p, index) in provinces">
```

Notice the `:value="p"`, where `p` is the province object, containing `Cities`.

After selecting the province, `province` can be used in the cities `<select>` to populate its `<options>` with city names:

```
<select v-model="city">
  <option v-for="(c, index) in province.Cities" :key="index">{{ c.name }}</option>
</select>
```

```js
const Provinces = [
        {
          "Province": "Foo",
          "Cities": [
            { "name": "Fooland" },
            { "name": "Fooville" }
          ]
        },
        {
          "Province": "Bar",
          "Cities": [
            { "name": "Barland" },
            { "name": "Barville" },
            { "name": "Barak" }
          ]
        }
      ];

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      province: '',
      city: '',
      provinces: Provinces
    }
  },
  watch: {
    province(newValue) {
      // reset city when province changes
      this.city = '';
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17"></script>

<div id="app">
  <select v-model="province">
    <option value="" disabled>Select province</option>
    <option v-for="(p, index) in provinces" :value="p" :key="index">{{ p.Province }}</option>
  </select>

  <select v-model="city" :disabled="!province">
    <option value="" disabled>Select city</option>
    <option v-for="(c, index) in province.Cities" :key="index">{{ c.name }}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, actually `provinces` is a computed property obtained from the store: `provinces () {  return  this.$store.state.provinces; }`. I tried your solution but get no result for cities selector's dropdown menu.

Comment: @Babr `provinces` being a computed property shouldn't make a difference. Did you add `:value="p"` to the `<option>`s of the first `<select>`?

Comment: Sorry, by adding  `:value="p"` it works fine. What does this magic stick?

Comment: @Babr Hopefully, my updated answer explains how `:value="p"` works. Let me know otherwise.